# Find Sum of the column in crystal report

Tags: c#, crystal-reports-2010

I tried to get sum for the column name 'AmtDue' with this below formula,But it shown the error "A number field or currency amount field is required here" when generate report.

```
Sum({CMS_Rpt_Payment_List;1.AmtDue})
```

Then I Used the below formula But I can't save the formula it shows "A field is required here"

```
Sum(ToNumber({CMS_Rpt_Payment_List;1.AmtDue}))
```

Is there any other way to get sum of the specific column.?

Comment: Is that CMS_Rpt_Payment_List is amount field and 1.Amt_Paid is group by field?

Comment: Finally I found a solution.I created the column field as formula converted as number.After that I created summary. Now ts working fine.Thank you friends for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sum(ToNumber({CMS_Rpt_Payment_List}),{1.AmtDue})
```

Comment: Why there is a semicolon between payment list and amt due,  
Is that CMS_Rpt_Payment_List is amount field and 1.Amt_Paid is group by field?